# CSS background-image gradient and border-line on bigger element

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a background-image with a line on the end.
The border or line should begin where the background-size ends.
The border line is grey in the concept. It should stay just one element.

```
  background-image: gradient-y(@color-grey-2, @color-white);
  background-position: left top;
  background-size: 100% 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with a 'multi stop' gradient? You should be able to achieve that effect. Play around with one of these: http://gradients.glrzad.com

Comment: how is the syntax for pixel stops instead of % cross-browser ?

Comment: [Multiple Backgrounds](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/) may be an alternative to multi-stops if you can't work it out that way.

Comment: I would assume that all you change is "%" to "px"

Comment: already think about multiply background, doesn't work like i imaging in this approach. will look px prefixed stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8Q79p/ OLD JSFIDDLE. (Wrapper)

http://jsfiddle.net/8Q79p/1/ Updated; if you want just one element, you can use `color-stop`

```
<div id="gradient">

</div>

#gradient{
    background: rgb(221,221,221); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(221,221,221,1) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 46%, rgba(149,149,149,1) 47%, rgba(149,149,149,1) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 49%, rgba(252,252,252,1) 100%, rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,rgba(221,221,221,1)), color-stop(46%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(47%,rgba(149,149,149,1)), color-stop(48%,rgba(149,149,149,1)), color-stop(49%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(252,252,252,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(27,27,27,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(221,221,221,1) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 46%,rgba(149,149,149,1) 47%,rgba(149,149,149,1) 48%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 49%,rgba(252,252,252,1) 100%,rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(221,221,221,1) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 46%,rgba(149,149,149,1) 47%,rgba(149,149,149,1) 48%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 49%,rgba(252,252,252,1) 100%,rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(221,221,221,1) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 46%,rgba(149,149,149,1) 47%,rgba(149,149,149,1) 48%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 49%,rgba(252,252,252,1) 100%,rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(221,221,221,1) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 46%,rgba(149,149,149,1) 47%,rgba(149,149,149,1) 48%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 49%,rgba(252,252,252,1) 100%,rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#dddddd', endColorstr='#1b1b1b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```